# compute mean of last 5 days of each month in R

Tags: r, date, dataframe, zoo, mean

I am finding this to be quite tricky.  I have an R time series data frame, consisting of a value for each day for about 50 years of data.  I would like to compute the mean of only the last 5 values for each month.  This would be simple if each month ended in the same 31st day, in which case I could just subset.  However, as we all know some months end in 31, some in 30, and then we have leap years.  So, is there a simple way to do this in R without having to write a complex indexing function to take account of all the possibilities including leap years?  Perhaps a function that works on zoo type objects?  The data frame is as follows:

```
        Date val
1 2014-01-06 1.49
2 2014-01-03 1.38
3 2014-01-02 1.34
4 2013-12-31 1.26
5 2013-12-30 2.11
6 2013-12-26 3.20
7 2013-12-25 3.00
8 2013-12-24 2.89
9 2013-12-23 2.90
10 2013-12-22 4.5
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333838/how-do-you-generate-a-sequence-of-the-last-day-of-the-month-over-two-years-in-r

Answer (score 3):

**tapply** Try this where `dd` is your data frame and we have assumed that the `Date` column is of class `"Date"`.   (If `dd` is already sorted in descending order of `Date` as it appears it might be in the question then we can shorten it a bit by replacing the anonymous function with `function(x) mean(head(x, 5))` .)

```
> tapply(dd$val, format(dd$Date, "%Y-%m"), function(x) mean(tail(sort(x), 5)))
 2013-12  2014-01 
2.492000 1.403333
```

**aggregate.zoo** In terms of zoo we can do this which returns another zoo object and its index is of class `"yearmon"`. (In the case of zoo it does not matter whether `dd` is sorted or not since zoo will sort it automatically.)

```
> library(zoo)
> z <- read.zoo(dd)
> aggregate(z, as.yearmon, function(x) mean(tail(x, 5)))
Dec 2013 Jan 2014 
2.492000 1.403333
```

*REVISIONS*.  Made some corrections.

Comment: Great thanks, this works quite well, looks like tapply does much of the grouping/aggregation I was attempting to do in the background.  I was also not aware that the apply can take custom functions as input.