# lubridate - incorrect month end sequence generated with %m+%

Tags: r, lubridate

I'm running into some strange behavior when using lubridate

```
dtStart<-ymd(20000430)
n<-24
dtStart %m+% months(0:n)
```

I'm expecting 24 month end dates, but I get the 30th of every month, including those months where there are 31 days:

```
[1] "2000-04-30 UTC" "2000-05-30 UTC" "2000-06-30 UTC" "2000-07-30 UTC" "2000-08-30 UTC" "2000-09-30 UTC" "2000-10-30 UTC" "2000-11-30 UTC" "2000-12-30 UTC"
[10] "2001-01-30 UTC" "2001-02-28 UTC" "2001-03-30 UTC" "2001-04-30 UTC" "2001-05-30 UTC" "2001-06-30 UTC" "2001-07-30 UTC" "2001-08-30 UTC" "2001-09-30 UTC"
[19] "2001-10-30 UTC" "2001-11-30 UTC" "2001-12-30 UTC" "2002-01-30 UTC" "2002-02-28 UTC" "2002-03-30 UTC" "2002-04-30 UTC"
```

Thanks for any advice on solving this using lubridate? (Not base R)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you generate a sequence of the last day of the month over two years in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333838/how-do-you-generate-a-sequence-of-the-last-day-of-the-month-over-two-years-in-r)

Comment: The question was specified as using lubridate, the possible duplicate uses base R.

Answer (score 0):

You're not really asking the last day but to *"add and subtract months to a date without exceeding the last day of the new month"* so the function is behaving exactly as expected.

Anyway, you can "trick" it a bit to get what you want by giving it a start date from a month that has the max number of days a month can have (31) and modifying the call accordingly:

```
dtStart<-ymd(20000331)
dtStart %m+% months(1:(n+1))
# [1] "2000-04-30 UTC" "2000-05-31 UTC" "2000-06-30 UTC" "2000-07-31 UTC" "2000-08-31 UTC" "2000-09-30 UTC" "2000-10-31 UTC"
# [8] "2000-11-30 UTC" "2000-12-31 UTC" "2001-01-31 UTC" "2001-02-28 UTC" "2001-03-31 UTC" "2001-04-30 UTC" "2001-05-31 UTC"
# [15] "2001-06-30 UTC" "2001-07-31 UTC" "2001-08-31 UTC" "2001-09-30 UTC" "2001-10-31 UTC" "2001-11-30 UTC" "2001-12-31 UTC"
# [22] "2002-01-31 UTC" "2002-02-28 UTC" "2002-03-31 UTC" "2002-04-30 UTC"
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:

```
ceiling_date(dtStart %m+% months(0:n),unit = "month")-days(1)
```

This code does a ceiling_date to the next month, and then subtract a day to find the last dat of the month.

Comment: explain why this works so the next user will understand the issue