# seq(as.Date("2016/3/31"),as.Date("2016/6/30"),by = "month")

Tags: r, date

The following R  code is not working properly:

```
seq(as.Date("2016/3/31"),as.Date("2016/6/30"),by = "month")
```

The output is:

> "2016-03-31" "2016-05-01" "2016-05-31"

But the expected output is:

> "2016-03-31" "2016-04-30" "2016-05-31""2016-06-30"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is a duplicate of [Generate a sequence of the last day of the month over two years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333838/how-do-you-generate-a-sequence-of-the-last-day-of-the-month-over-two-years-in-r) and they suggested to do the following

```
ymd("2010-02-01")+ months(0:23)-days(1)
```

Simply specify the first day of the next month and generate a sequence from that but subtract 1 days from it to get the last day of the preceding month.

Comment: Thanks for answer :).  If i reduce last date it performing perfectly seq(as.Date("2016/3/30"),as.Date("2016/6/30"),by = "month".