# Seq in R not working correctly

Tags: r, date, datetime

I want sequence of dates by months, so I tried seq() command in R
and what I got is

```
> seq(as.Date("2016-10-31"), length=3, by="1 month") 
[1] "2016-10-31" "2016-12-01" "2016-12-31"
```

any other solution ?

Comment: What is your expected output?  If it is the last day of each month , you can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333838/how-do-you-generate-a-sequence-of-the-last-day-of-the-month-over-two-years-in-r)

Comment: expected output is         "2016-10-31" "2016-11-30" "2016-12-31"

Comment: That function has that bug but you can do the same by                                                                                                           > seq.Date((as.Date("2016-10-31")+1),(as.Date("2016-12-31")+1),by="1 months") - 1                                                                                                  [1] "2016-10-31" "2016-11-30" "2016-12-31"