# Generate date sequence by months

Tags: r, lubridate

This is the result I want:

```r
library(lubridate)

res <- structure(
  c(
    16160, 16251, 16343, 16435, 16525, 16616, 16708, 
    16800, 16891, 16982, 17074, 17166, 17256, 17347, 17439, 17531, 
    17621, 17712, 17804, 17896, 17986, 18077, 18169, 18261, 18352, 
    18443, 18535, 18627, 18717, 18808, 18900
  ), 
  class = "Date"
)

res
#>  [1] "2014-03-31" "2014-06-30" "2014-09-30" "2014-12-31" "2015-03-31"
#>  [6] "2015-06-30" "2015-09-30" "2015-12-31" "2016-03-31" "2016-06-30"
#> [11] "2016-09-30" "2016-12-31" "2017-03-31" "2017-06-30" "2017-09-30"
#> [16] "2017-12-31" "2018-03-31" "2018-06-30" "2018-09-30" "2018-12-31"
#> [21] "2019-03-31" "2019-06-30" "2019-09-30" "2019-12-31" "2020-03-31"
#> [26] "2020-06-30" "2020-09-30" "2020-12-31" "2021-03-31" "2021-06-30"
#> [31] "2021-09-30"
```

I have to generate it as a sequence though.

I have managed to get the result using a while loop:

```r
dateA <- min(res)
dateB <- max(res)
by <- months(3)

# initialize a vector to contain all dates:
myres <- dateA

while (TRUE) {
  n <- length(myres)
  next_date <- ceiling_date(myres[n] %m+% by, unit = by) - 1
  
  # if next_date is less than dateB, add it to myres & continue looping:
  if (next_date < dateB) {
    myres[n + 1] <- next_date
    next
  }
  
  # if next_date is equal to or greater than dateB, add it and terminate loop:
  if (next_date >= dateB) {
    myres[n + 1] <- next_date
    break
  }
}

identical(res, myres)
#> [1] TRUE
```

I was hoping for something like:

```r
x <- seq.Date(from = dateA, to = dateB, by = "3 months")
x
#>  [1] "2014-03-31" "2014-07-01" "2014-10-01" "2014-12-31" "2015-03-31"
#>  [6] "2015-07-01" "2015-10-01" "2015-12-31" "2016-03-31" "2016-07-01"
#> [11] "2016-10-01" "2016-12-31" "2017-03-31" "2017-07-01" "2017-10-01"
#> [16] "2017-12-31" "2018-03-31" "2018-07-01" "2018-10-01" "2018-12-31"
#> [21] "2019-03-31" "2019-07-01" "2019-10-01" "2019-12-31" "2020-03-31"
#> [26] "2020-07-01" "2020-10-01" "2020-12-31" "2021-03-31" "2021-07-01"
```

But that doesn't seem to work.

Is there a simpler way than the `while` loop? I'd appreciate any pointers in the right direction.

Comment: It is basically a duplicate of what I answered here eleven (!!) years ago:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333838/generate-a-sequence-of-the-last-day-of-the-month-over-two-years

Comment: This one doesn't use length as input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is most elegantly solved by taking the day of the month component out of the equation while you are generating the sequence. With the [clock](https://clock.r-lib.org) package, you can generate a month precision sequence, then easily set the day to the last day of the month.

```r
library(clock)

start <- as.Date("2014-03-31")
end <- as.Date("2021-09-30")

start <- calendar_narrow(as_year_month_day(start), "month")
end <- calendar_narrow(as_year_month_day(end), "month")

# Month precision dates
start
#> <year_month_day<month>[1]>
#> [1] "2014-03"
end
#> <year_month_day<month>[1]>
#> [1] "2021-09"

seq(start, end, by = 3) |>
  set_day("last") |>
  as.Date()
#>  [1] "2014-03-31" "2014-06-30" "2014-09-30" "2014-12-31" "2015-03-31"
#>  [6] "2015-06-30" "2015-09-30" "2015-12-31" "2016-03-31" "2016-06-30"
#> [11] "2016-09-30" "2016-12-31" "2017-03-31" "2017-06-30" "2017-09-30"
#> [16] "2017-12-31" "2018-03-31" "2018-06-30" "2018-09-30" "2018-12-31"
#> [21] "2019-03-31" "2019-06-30" "2019-09-30" "2019-12-31" "2020-03-31"
#> [26] "2020-06-30" "2020-09-30" "2020-12-31" "2021-03-31" "2021-06-30"
#> [31] "2021-09-30"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-15 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

**1) Base R** Add one to the start and end dates to get the start and end of the next month, generate the sequence and subtract one to get the end of the months. No packages are used.

```
st <- as.Date("2014-03-31")
en <- as.Date("2021-09-30")
seq(st + 1, en + 1, by = "3 months") - 1
##  [1] "2014-03-31" "2014-06-30" "2014-09-30" "2014-12-31" "2015-03-31"
##  [6] "2015-06-30" "2015-09-30" "2015-12-31" "2016-03-31" "2016-06-30"
## [11] "2016-09-30" "2016-12-31" "2017-03-31" "2017-06-30" "2017-09-30"
## [16] "2017-12-31" "2018-03-31" "2018-06-30" "2018-09-30" "2018-12-31"
## [21] "2019-03-31" "2019-06-30" "2019-09-30" "2019-12-31" "2020-03-31"
## [26] "2020-06-30" "2020-09-30" "2020-12-31" "2021-03-31" "2021-06-30"
## [31] "2021-09-30"
```

**2) yearmon** It would also be possible to create a yearmon sequence consisting only of year/month with no day and then use `as.Date.yearmon` with the `frac=1` argument which instructs it to use end of month in the conversion to Date class.

```
library(zoo)

st <- as.yearmon("2014-03-31")
en <- as.yearmon("2021-09-30")
as.Date(seq(st, en, 3/12), frac = 1)
```

**3) mondate** The mondate package understands end of months.  Calculate the difference in months between the start and end and then add the appropriate sequence as shown.

```
library(mondate)

st <- mondate("2014-03-31")
en <- mondate("2021-09-30")
as.Date(mondate(st + seq(0, as.numeric(en - st), 3)))
```

**4) lubridate** Find the number of months between the two dates and then add a sequence of months.  In that case it will understand that we want month ends.

```
library(lubridate)

st <- ymd("2014-03-31")
en <- ymd("2021-09-30")
st %m+% months(seq(0, round(interval(st, en) / months(1)), 3))
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you're starting with just the extremes,

```r
res <- range(res)
res
# [1] "2014-03-31" "2021-09-30"
do.call(seq.Date, c(as.list(lubridate::ceiling_date(res, unit = "month")), by = "3 months")) - 1L
#  [1] "2014-03-31" "2014-06-30" "2014-09-30" "2014-12-31" "2015-03-31" "2015-06-30" "2015-09-30" "2015-12-31" "2016-03-31"
# [10] "2016-06-30" "2016-09-30" "2016-12-31" "2017-03-31" "2017-06-30" "2017-09-30" "2017-12-31" "2018-03-31" "2018-06-30"
# [19] "2018-09-30" "2018-12-31" "2019-03-31" "2019-06-30" "2019-09-30" "2019-12-31" "2020-03-31" "2020-06-30" "2020-09-30"
# [28] "2020-12-31" "2021-03-31" "2021-06-30" "2021-09-30"
```

If you're not as comfortable with the `do.call` part, then

```r
res <- lubridate::ceiling_date(range(res), unit = "month")
res
# [1] "2014-04-01" "2021-10-01"
seq.Date(res[1], res[2], by = "3 months")
#  [1] "2014-04-01" "2014-07-01" "2014-10-01" "2015-01-01" "2015-04-01" "2015-07-01" "2015-10-01" "2016-01-01" "2016-04-01"
# [10] "2016-07-01" "2016-10-01" "2017-01-01" "2017-04-01" "2017-07-01" "2017-10-01" "2018-01-01" "2018-04-01" "2018-07-01"
# [19] "2018-10-01" "2019-01-01" "2019-04-01" "2019-07-01" "2019-10-01" "2020-01-01" "2020-04-01" "2020-07-01" "2020-10-01"
# [28] "2021-01-01" "2021-04-01" "2021-07-01" "2021-10-01"
```